# Ошибка при добавлении в словарь\файл\shelve?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу адресную книгу по книге Byte of Pyton (задание). При добавлении нового контакта, выдает ошибку. Уже разные варианты перепробовал, не могу понять в чем дело.

```
import shelve

class PhoneBook():
    mybook = {}
    f = shelve.open('mybook', flag='n')
    newbook = {}
    def add_person(self, newcont, new_phone):
        self.newcont = newcont
        self.new_phone = new_phone
        self.newbook = {self.newcont: self.new_phone}
        self.mybook.update([self.newbook])
        f = self.mybook
```

Ошибка следующая: До этого не было этой ошибки, но просто не добавляло в файл.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonWork/Kate/phonebookclassi.py", line 76, in <module>
    phonebook.add_person(newcont, new_phone)
  File "C:/PythonWork/Kate/phonebookclassi.py", line 12, in add_person
    self.mybook.update([self.newbook])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: А в коде вашем где ошибочная строка?

Comment: Обновил ошибку, оказывает с предыдущей версии скинул.

Answer (score 1):

Перво-наперво заглянем в [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update). Там сказано, какие объекты принимает метод `update`:

1) Другой словарь.

2) Итерируемую коллекцию (список), состоящую из пар ключ-значение.

3) Именованные аргументы.

Вы же ему подсовываете список со словарем, такого варианта не предусмотрено.

Три метода:

```
# 1 Метод
a = {"a": 1}
b = {"c": 2}
a.update(b)
print(a)
>>> {"a": 1, "c": 2}

# 2 Метод
a = {"a": 1}
b = [("c", 2), ("yo", 199)]
a.update(b)
print(a)
>>> {"a": 1, "c": 2, "yo": 199}

# 3 метод
a = {"a": 1}
a.update(c=2, yo=199)
print(a)
>>> {"a": 1, "c": 2, "yo": 199}
```